# OneNote - How can I recover from an accidental Section deletion?

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-onenote-2010

I have several OneNote notebooks stored on my SkyDrive and love being able to reference my notes from all of my devices.

Recently, the iOS version was updated with new features.  When I was trying to add a new note, I accidentally created a new Section.  When I tried to delete the Section, the screen refreshed and I picked "Delete" on a section with tons of critical notes.  I tried "undo", but it didn't track this change.  I checked my SkyDrive recycle bin, but it didn't have this Section (or any OneNote notes).  I checked my local SkyDrive cache on my laptop, but it only had an internet shortcut to my OneNote file instead of the notebook, itself.

I'm sick that I lost these notes.  I have piles of backup solutions in place, but nothing helps in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was so easy, I'm surprised no one answered!

In OneNote 2010 (I assume is similar for other versions), open the backstage (File menu) and look to the right.  There's a button labeled "Open Backups"!

On my system, this opened Explorer to:

```
C:\Users\kevinbuchan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneNote\14.0\Backup
```

Recovery was easy now!

Comment: The solution helped me to recover a section deleted in OneNote for Windows 8. I installed OneNote 2013, synced the notebook and restored the section using Open Backups button.

Comment: OK, so I have the backup open.  How do I now make it part of my notebook again?